# change backround image of another div when hovering over list item

Tags: javascript, css

I have a list in a div and I would like to change the background image of the parent div (#homepage_container) when I hover over a list item.

here's the site:-

http://www.thebalancedbody.ca/

Is this possible? I'm guessing I'll have to use javascript.

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use JS.
Better to learn something like jQuery.
With it you will have to do something like

```
var images = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', ...]

for (var i = 0; i < li_count; ++i) // li_count is the number of li's
    $('li:eq(' + i + ')').mouseover(function() {$('#homepage_container').css('background-image', images[i]})
```

Anyway, if you wish to use such kinds of techniques, you have to learn JS.
See http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp and for basics and http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials for jQuery.

Comment: Why do JQuery when this is simple with pure javascript?

Comment: That's what I'm looking for but not sure how to implement this so that each list item hover shows a different background. 

Is that all I'll need at the top once I've loaded jquery, I won't need anything in the list item itself in terms of JS?

Comment: > Why do JQuery when this is simple with pure javascript?

Because pure JS DOM manipulation is ugly, while jQuery is nice, simple and powerful

> That's what I'm looking for but not sure how to implement this so that each list item hover shows a different background.

You can use some kind of array with images in the same order your `li`s are, see updated answer.

Comment: @Jonathan Lyon: yes, it's all you'll need (this edited version). But you'll be using a strong but heavy tool for something small and simple. Also, keeping the hovered-image synchronized with the right `li` might be confusing when changing the menu. (+0)

Comment: @ANeves, the tool is not heavy, it's lightweight and easy to learn %)

Comment: @Guard, I somehow disagree. He only really needs to attach a function to the `hover` of each `li`, and send an image url to that function. That function can then get `#homepage_container` and change it's `background-image` to whatever the function received as argument. I find this is pretty light in comparison to using JQuery. Which is a mighty tool, and greatly simplifies the medium or advanced use of JavaScript, yes! But for this case, I believe it is overkill.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite simple with pure javascript.

```
function changeBg(newBg)
{
    var imgdiv = document.getElementById("divwithbackground");
    imgdiv.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + newBg + ")";
}
```

Or using sprites:

```
imgdiv.style.backgroundPosition = "new position";
```

This can be executed on mouseover for any of your `li`'s. Event registration in javascript can be done many ways, but to do it in script, I recommend QuirksMode's method [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/eventSimple.html).

Something like:

```
function addEventSimple(obj,evt,fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener)
        obj.addEventListener(evt,fn,false);
    else if (obj.attachEvent)
        obj.attachEvent('on'+evt,fn);
}
```

And on load:

```
// get the list items
var ul = document.getElementById("ulId");
var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

// add event handlers
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++)
{
    addEventSimple(lis[i], "mouseover", (function(j) {
        return function() { 
            // get your background image from the li somehow
            changeBg(lis[j].id + "_bg.png");
        };
    })(i)); // use a closure to capture the current value of "i"
}
```

Comment: enclose it in a function that receives the image location, and show an example on how to set the function on two `li` so that the parent div gets different backgrounds when hovering each of the divs - and that'll answer OP's question.

Comment: +1: yes. I'd have put, on every li, something like `<li onhover="changeBG('wallaby.png')" ...` instead - but not being very wise in JavaScript, I'll trust your approach to be better.

Comment: That's valid too. I just like to keep everything in script instead of mixing it into the html.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing the Jquery Library for this (jquery.com)

Just add this to your header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">

<script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {

          $('li').hover(function(){

         $('#homepage_container').css('background-image' : 'whatever.png');

            }

      });
</script>
```

Comment: Needs different bgs for different `li`.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care about IE6, you could do it with CSS:

```
#homepage_container { background: url(normal.png); }
#homepage_container:hover { background: url(hover.png); }
```

Comment: This isn't the same. The OP wants to change the background of a _different_ element on hover, and `#homepage_container` is not inside the `li`'s being hovered.

Comment: Indeed, I guess I should get some sleep. Thanks! :)

Comment: -1: fix or delete, please, if you know it not to be an answer.